Tying shoes on Shabbat if you don’t plan to untie them in a day
According to Halacha, is it permissible for you to tie shoes on Shabbat if you don’t plan on untying them within a day? Or no, is it prohibited and you are obligated to untie them within 24 hours?

Shulchan aruch orach chaim 317/5

עניבה מותר דלאו קשר הוא: הגה ואפי' אם עושה קשר אחד למטה נוהגין בו היתר: (אגור):
5. A bow is permitted because it is not a knot. RAMA: even if one ties a single knot beneath it we are accustomed to permit it.

Mishna berura seif katan 29

(כט) נוהגין בו היתר - וכתבו האחרונים הא דנוהגין היתר בקשר אחד למטה היינו דוקא כשעשוי להתיר בו ביום ומשום דע"י עניבה ע"ג קשר עדיין אינו נקרא מעשה אומן אבל אם היא לקיימא על איזה זמן כגון בלולב וכיוצא בו אסור לעשות קשר למטה אלא עניבה בלבד ורשאי לעשות שתי עניבות זה ע"ג זה וכן יש לנהוג:

Shmirat Shabat Kehilchata 16/56 (in the new Hebrew edition) addresses this question based on the aforementioned mishna berura that tying shoes for longer then 24 hours is not permitted.
